# jqTouch - Making an image trigger an animation, rather than a <li>

Tags: jquery, jqtouch

Playing around a bit more with jqTouch and am running into a problem with images that should link to a separate page.

My code is

```
<div id="home" class="current">
<div class="toolbar">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <img src="images/logo.png" />
</div>
<div class="images">
    <a href="#largeImage"><img src="/images/thumbnail_1.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="#largeImage"><img src="/images/thumbnail_2.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="#largeImage"><img src="/images/thumbnail_3.jpg" /></a> 
</div>
</div>
<div id="largeImage">
<div class="toolbar">
    <h1>Large Image</h1>
    <a class="back" href="#">Back</a>
</div>
<div>Large Image will be loaded here</div>
</div>
```

So, jqTouch doesn't recognize the anchors wrapped around the images, it seems. If i put those in an unordered list - it behaves as expected, and the page transitions to the #largeImage screen.

Any idea how to get this to work without making the images an unordered list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to control the slide transition? You may want to try initializing jQTouch with a different "SlideSelector" option:

```
$.jQTouch({slideSelector: "body > * > div a"})
```

This might work in your case, you may need to tweak around with the selector to make it work as you want, [read more about it here.](http://code.google.com/p/jqtouch/wiki/Animations)

Comment: No, the transition is fine. I'm just trying to target the #largeImage div... Right now, it doesn't seem able to find it, and is triggering a call to "back"

Comment: Actually - this is totally right. Ignore my previous comment. THANK YOU!

Comment: no prob! Glad it worked. I def recommend checking out their wiki, its fairly in depth, which is nice!

Answer (score 0):

Yes the transition works fine!

But still, navigating back in the history does not work.
Once you are in the largeImage Panel, clicking on Back does nothing...

Any additional hint?